# Is this code a Keylogger? What does it do?

Tags: powershell, security

Due to Windows10 task manager I have a powershell.exe running which is continously consuming 8% CPU and blocking 64MB of RAM. After inspecting my Windows event log I found a pipeline event (800) with subsequent code:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
function Run-Server() {
  param([string]$h);
  $b = New-Object byte[] 8;
  $p = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream -ArgumentList @([System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In, $h);
  if ($p) {
    $l = $p.Read($b, 0, 8); while ($l -gt 7) {
      $c = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($b, 0); $l = System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($b, 4);
      $t = $null; if ($l -gt 0) {
        $t1 = New-Object byte[] $l;
        $l = $p.Read($t1, 0, $t1.Length);
        $t = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($t1, 0, $l) }
      if ($c -eq 1) { Invoke-Expression $t } elseif ($c -eq 9) { break } $l = $p.Read($b, 0, 8) } 
   $p.Dispose() 
    } 
} Run-Server -h 728
```

I'm working in a corporate environment and I'm not a Powershell expert, but it seems as the script is catching byte by byte and make a string out of it? Do you have any idea what this script could be used for? Do you think it can cause the given indication of 8% CPU and 64MB RAM usage?

Comment: This looks like a (malicious) listener which takes commands from another application.

Comment: Might not be malicious if in a corporate environment. Could be something used by someone with legitimate need to send commands. Suggest you ask your IT support

Comment: I've already talked to our Patch/Security Management guy as well as someone who is familar with Powershell. They said they don't know such kind of process in our corporate environment. That's why I'm asking here in addition. I would like to receive confirmation or alternative ideas. Our IT department officially don't such a script..

Comment: Do you have any idea what I could do to get more information?

Answer (score 3):

I formatted the code, changed the variable names and added some comments to make it easier to understand:

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core

function Run-Server() {

    param(
        [string]$h
    );


    $buffer = New-Object byte[] 8;

    # Creates an annonymous pipe
    $pipe = New-Object System.IO.Pipes.AnonymousPipeClientStream -ArgumentList @([System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::In, $h);

    if ($pipe) {

        # Read up to 8 bytes from the pipe
        $readBytes = $pipe.Read($buffer,0, 8); #(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count);

        # if it managed to read 8 bytes
        while ($readBytes -gt 7) {

            # Seems the sender is sending some kind of 'command' or instruction. 
            # If command is '1' means execute the rest as a script
            # If command is '9' means terminate
            $command = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($buffer,0); 

            # Seems that in position 4 it sends how big the text will be
            $textSize = [System.BitConverter]::ToInt32($buffer,4); # ToInt32 (byte[] value, int startIndex);

            # based on the $textSize, read the full message and convert it to string ($text)
            $text = $null;
            if ($readBytes -gt 0) {
                $text1 = New-Object byte[] $textSize;
                $readBytes = $pipe.Read($text1, 0, $text1.Length);
                $text = [System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetString($text1, 0, $readBytes) 
            }

            if ($command -eq 1) { 
                # Scary! execute the text string that came from the pipe
                Invoke-Expression $text 
            }
            elseif ($command -eq 9) {
                 break 
            } 
            $readBytes = $pipe.Read($buffer,0, 8) 
        } 
        $pipe.Dispose() 
    } 
} 

Run-Server -h 728
```

Infor about pipe: [AnonymousPipeClientStream Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.pipes.anonymouspipeclientstream?view=netframework-4.8)

That codes creates an ***In*** pipe with handle `728` and receives a script from another process, then it executes the script

Some details:

The first message seems to be a kind of ***command*** ($c) and an indication of how big the script will be ($l)

Then it reads a second message of size ($l) and, if ***command* == 1**, it executes the second message as if it would be a powershell script: `Invoke-Expression $t` (scary!)

Comment: Wow, thanks. And do you think it could be a somehow official solution for automated remote administration (for beeing used in patch and update management) or would you say that its style is more like a malicious script which isn't/shouldn't be used officially? I'm working in Germany. We have some kind of strict personal data collection restrictions. Even in companies. Would you expect it beeing a Keylogger or would you say that its primary intend is something different? I trust your expectation, but your conclusion isn't 100% clear to me since I don't understand the given topic very well.

Comment: I am not sure why you have this, and who is running it. In terms of GDPR this has nothing to do, it is not a keyloger, it is waaay worse :). This receives a random text and it execute it as a script. It could be anything, like "format C:\". I cannot imagine why you would do this.

Comment: I don't know if it matters but according to the Windows event logging the handle differs per day of beeing active. The script is also beeing runned twice with a different  sequence number. The first one starts with: `& {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core` and sequence number: 15. The second starts with `Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core` and has secquence number: 17. The order can be wrong. Both scripts are beeing initiated on the same time according to the available timestamp for execution.

Comment: Are the scripts still running periodically? where do you see it running? what if you change the script to log all what it is doing? for example, instead of `Invoke-Expression` you can write $text to a file, that way you can see what scripts are actually being executed. This code just executes any script that is given

Comment: Well... maybe i was not clear enough. This can only be called by a parent process, so the process that opens the pipe has to execute the powershell as well

Comment: Yes, everyday day for a week now. It starts after I logged in for the first time and restarted (not periodically) after I killed it in the task manager. I've seen it first in my task manager after it was constantly blocking CPU and RAM% and turned my cooling fans on, even when doing nothing. It doesn't seem to create any noticable network traffic or HDD IO. The only way for me to see it is via the Windows 10 Event logging / Application and Service Logs / Windows Power Shell / Filter Logs on Event 800. I sadly don't know how to manipulate the script as you recommend.

Comment: In logging and after some presequel meta information the script starts like this: `HostName=ConsoleHost
HostVersion=5.1.17134.858
 HostId=4d357548-6508-4393-b558-ecb4b48ba51f
HostApplication=C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe -NonInteractive -NoProfile -Command & {Add-Type -AssemblyName System.Core
function Run-Server() { param([string]$h); $b [...]`

Comment: Use Process Explorer (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to grab information on who is starting the script. That is very important because the pipe is open parent -> child

Comment: Hey @Christian, did you figure out what the script was for or who was invoking it?

Comment: Hello Carlos, partwise. But still not sure. Before I left on that day I had a chat with our IT guys. In the end I was ready to dump my machine and have had the plan to do a backup but before I started the backup, I decided to start a deep scan with "Symantec Endpoint Protection". While performing the scan I noticed something interesting: The scan shows a similar characteristic as the script (CPU, RAM). So I started to think that the powershell.exe could be called from Symantec. On the next day I told the IT guys about my idee and they somehow agreed.

Comment: They don't seem know it better. I'm still a little bit curious since my colleagues are also using this program but don't have the previous mentioned script in their logs.. Basically Symantec could make sense to me, since the scheduled quick/deep scans have to have full control for qurantining, deleting, et cetera. I could be ok with it, but as beeing sad: My colleague(s) don't have the same log entry/entries as me. What do you think?

Comment: Hey Christian, I think your goal should be to see which process is executing this, that will give you a very good idea on why is this being executed.

Comment: Hello Carlos, Thanks for the advice. I've done that now. Which additional columns have to get activated? There are quite many available. Or in other words: How to identify the calling process?

Answer (score 2):

Folks, I'm from Snow Software and can confirm that this is a legit code executed by Snow Inventory Agent to run PowerShell scripts that are deployed with the agents for gathering more advanced information about the device and certain apps installed on it. It does indeed run the anonymous pipe and send the Powershell code as text sourced from the encrypted script files that are deployed together with the agent. The gathered data is used by Snow Software and Technology Asset Management product suite and is deployed by large organizations to optimize technology spend, get visibility, and manageability of the technology assets.
Let me know if you have more questions!

Answer (score 1):

I happened to run into the same issue. After some digging through my system (grep), I found
out that the offending code occurs in an executable 'snowagent.exe'. As far as I can tell it is used by our (company) IT department to get an inventory of the applications installed on my machine, and maybe more.
As such, I conclude that it is at least not a big issue (virus/malware). Still, if I am
hampered by it (i.e. eating away 13% CPU), I just kill it.
gr M.